# What are some other places to buy MTB frames online?

Tags: mountain-bike, parts, frames, shopping

I am looking for sites that sell bike frames online. i find many sites list all things (forks) but stop short with frames.

The best places I have found are:
http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/
and
http://www.jensonusa.com/

Open to places that only sell their own brand but more after places which stock many brands.

I am looking at the low-end of the price range too

Also i am located in Australia. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to check on eBay, being in Australia you might even find someone closer to you than those big online stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my results:

http://www.chainreactioncycles.com
http://www.cyclingdeal.com.au
http://www.cellbikes.com.au
http://www.moruyabicycles.com.au
http://www.bicyclehero.com
http://www.bikes.com.au
http://www.torpedo7.com.au
http://www.bicyclestore.com.au
http://www.aerotechdesigns.com
http://www.cyclelink.com.au
http://www.hillbrick.com.au
http://www.nashbar.com
http://www.velogear.com.au
http://www.probikekit.com/au
http://www.pricepoint.com
http://shop.titusti.com
http://on-one.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

In the US http://www.performancebike.com and http://www.nashbar.com are two big online bike outfitters.  I don't know that either sells bare frames, but they do sell a wide variety of stuff.

And of course a number of custom/low volume bike builders sell bare frames.

[Here](http://www.mikebentley.com/bike/bikemfg.htm) is a pretty good list of bike & frame manufacturers.

Comment: [Pricepoint.com](http://www.pricepoint.com/default.htm) too.  I've only ordered parts, no frames.

Answer (score 1):

On One are great! They have a USA store open now which might ship to Aus for less (from UK it is 25-70GBP)

http://on-one.co.uk

http://shop.titusti.com